# Tag or inherit the same code in Django template with minor changes

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-template-filters

I have a bunch of code that I will need to use repeatedly on a page, and on multiple pages. For example, here is a shorter version of the code:

```
<a href="#"
   data-toggle="popover"
   title="{% for terms in s_terms %}{% if terms.slug == 'neuron' %}{{terms.title}}{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
   data-content="{% for terms in s_terms %}{% if terms.slug == 'neuron' %}{{terms.para_one}}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">
  Toggle popover
</a>
```

There is a lot more code in the block. Now, for obvious reasons I do not want to keep repeating such large chunks of code. I am a fan of the DRY approach.

However, I can't figure out how to render this same piece of code repeatedly. The only thing that would change is the word = "neuron" in there. I thought of using template tags, but that didn't work.

I tried saving the code as a separate file, and inherit it within my template, but then I can't change the keyword ('neuron'). I also tried creating a separate dynamic page, and include that in my Django template, but looks like the include tag only works for templates, and not for dynamic pages.

Can anyone help, please? Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Why didn't template tags work? They are the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `return value.replace` to pass a word and have the template tag replace the word with the code above, while including the word within the code. I was calling it in the template as `neuron | my_custom_tag.` I was just getting a template error, though. Would you mind taking a stab at defining the template tag... not sure why it kept giving me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Django template built-in template tag [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

From the documentation:

> Loads a template and renders it with the current context. This is a
>   way of “including” other templates within a template.

So, you can just extract your snippet in a separate template and then use it with:

```
{% include "snippet_template.html" %}
```

Additionally, you can pass a variable to the include template using the `with` keyword - you would use this to pass your `word` parameter:

```
{% include "snippet_template.html" with word="neuron" %}
```

Comment: Thanks @bonidjukic. That's exactly what I am trying to do, but I'm stuck on how to modify my code within the snippet_template,htm, so that it knows where to insert the "word" (in this example: neuron). Could you please help with that?

Comment: Well, once you pass your `word` variable to the snippet template, it's going to be available within it; e.g.: `...{% if terms.slug == word %}...`

Comment: This worked well when I tried it by inserting directly into the django template, but not when I tried to pass it through a database using the `safe` command. Since, it's a slightly different issue, and I am hoping that I'm not the only one trying to find a solution to this, I created a separate OS question. Would you mind taking a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797931/passing-the-include-tag-via-django-admin-or-database], if you feel comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

As @bonidjukic wrote the `include` statement is what you search.

But `include` statement inside for-loop could reach one weakness of Django template Engine (vs Jinja). You include just variables, so it will be fast.

In the case of needing tags (like `trans`), Django will load tags at each include. Where Jinja will have global "tags".

So just be careful, with how you DRY you templates.

Comment: Thanks @Zulu, that makes sense. I am not familiar with Jinja at all, but I'll try to familiarize myself with the documentation later today.